# classPath:Resolve does not resolve method invocations properly under some circumstances

Tags: java, jqassistant

I have a method m1 in class A that has a variable b of type class B and m1 invokes a method m2 in class B by calling b.m2(...). Now, method m2 is not implemented in class B but in a class C from which B has been derived. If you run jQAssistant on that scenario, I get the following relationships if all three class belong to same artifact:
(A)-[:DECLARES]->(m1)-[:INVOKES]->(m2)<-[:DECLARES]-(B)<-[:EXTENDS]-(C)
and (C)-[:DECLARES]->(m2').
Note that (B)-[:DECLARES]->(m2) is a kind of synthetic declaration as m2 is not really declared by B but just inherited.

But suppose that class A belongs to a different artifact than class B and C. Then the resolve mechanism does not generate the synthetic declare in the resolved class B. To be more precise, scanning A's artifact will generate:
(A)-[:DECLARES]->(m1)-[:INVOKES]->(m2'')<-[:DECLARES]-(B').
And resolving via the concept classPath:Resolve will create:
(B')-[:RESOLVES_TO]->(B) but there will be no (B)-[:DECLARES]->(m2) and hence m2'' cannot be resolved to m2. Thus, the :INVOKES relationship cannot be resolved either.

Comment: Sounds like an issue that must be fixed, can I ask you to create one on GitHub? Cheers, Dirk

Answer (score 0):

For me the following concepts worked:

```
<concept id="missingResolves:AddInheritedMethodsToResolvedTypes">
    <requiresConcept refId="classpath:ResolveMember"/>
    <description>Sometimes the method needed to resolve a method m1 declared in a type t1 is not directly declared in the resolved type t2, but just inherited by t2, then we add this method to t2 (as synthetic-declare).</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
    MATCH (t1:Type)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->(t2:Type), (t1)-[:DECLARES]->(m1:Method)
    WHERE  NOT (m1)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->()
    WITH DISTINCT t2, m1.signature AS methodSignature
    MERGE (t2)-[:DECLARES {synthetic: true}]->(m2:Method {signature: methodSignature})
    RETURN t2.name as type, methodSignature ORDER BY t2.name, methodSignature
    ]]></cypher>
</concept>

<concept id="missingResolves:ResolveMethodsUsingInheritedMethodsInResolvedTypes">
    <requiresConcept refId="missingResolves:AddInheritedMethodsToResolvedTypes"/>
    <description>Uses the synthetic methods added by the "AddInheritedMethodsToResolvedTypes" concept to add missing method resolves.</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
    MATCH (t1:Type)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->(t2:Type), (t1)-[:DECLARES]->(m1:Method)
    WHERE  NOT (m1)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->()
    WITH t1, t2, m1 MATCH (t2)-[:DECLARES {synthetic: true}]->(m2:Method)
    WHERE  m1.signature = m2.signature
    MERGE (m1)-[:RESOLVES_TO {resolved:true}]->(m2)
    RETURN count(m1) as ResolvedMethods
    ]]></cypher>
</concept>

<concept id="missingResolves:ResolveInvokesAgain">
    <requiresConcept refId="classpath:ResolveInvokes"/>
    <requiresConcept refId="missingResolves:ResolveMethodsUsingInheritedMethodsInResolvedTypes"/>
    <description>Resolve method invocations again (same as in original jQAssistant).</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
    MATCH (m:Method)-[i:INVOKES]->(m1:Method)-[:RESOLVES_TO]->(m2:Method)
    WHERE NOT (m)-[:INVOKES{lineNumber:i.lineNumber,resolved:true}]->(m2)
    MERGE (m)-[:INVOKES{lineNumber:i.lineNumber,resolved:true}]->(m2)
    RETURN count(i) as ResolvedInvocations      
    ]]></cypher>
</concept>

<concept id="missingResolves:Correct">
    <requiresConcept refId="classpath:Resolve"/>
    <requiresConcept refId="missingResolves:ResolveInvokesAgain"/>
    <description>Performs a complete corrected resolve.</description>
    <cypher><![CDATA[
    MATCH ()-[r:RESOLVES_TO]->() RETURN count(r) as ResolvedElements
    ]]></cypher>
</concept>
```